# Change an S-Corp to a Sole Proprietorship

Tags: business, tax-law

**A bit of background:** I'm working towards building a business selling on Amazon. I've been doing this for less than 2 months, and have less than $200 in sales, whereas I've spent about $700 on this. In other words, there's been no profit yet.

When I first started, I was advised to register as an S-Corp to avoid paying self employment taxes, and for various other reasons as well.

**The problem:** I'm beginning to think I should have just gone with a Sole Proprietorship. I mean, that's what I am, just one person doing business for herself.  The S-Corp requires me to pay myself a wage, have paychecks including income tax, etc, etc.

**My question is two-fold.** **1.** Other than being taxed as self employed vs employed by the company, what are the differences between an SCorp and a Sole Proprietorship, and what are the advantages and disadvantages of each? I know so little about this sort of thing that I don't really even know how to present arguments for and against each side, other than that it seems like Sole Proprietorship seems to be more accurate for what I'm doing.

**2.** If I do need to switch, I assume that involves dissolving the S-Corp.  What do I need to do for that? I'm registered to collect sales tax in three states, though I don't owe anything to any of them. I assume I need to inform them and the federal government.  Or, is there some paperwork I can file that just changes the type of my business?

I would dearly love to hire a CPA, but I have extremely limited funds for starting this business, and can't afford one.

Many, many thanks in advance.

Comment: May I suggest that you edit the question to not ask us what you should do (we can't give legal advice), and instead ask a what the legal consequences of a Sole Proprietorship are (though it should be narrower than that).

Comment: Thank you- I've edited it. Hopefully this will be acceptable.